# Unable to launch project in chrome which is created using angular-cli

Tags: angular, google-chrome, angular-cli

create an angular project using angular-CLI as mentioned in https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Run `ng serve`

access application using http://localhost:4200/

I am able to access my angular app in Firefox without any issues
whereas in chrome I am getting

> "Refused connection" error.
>   This site can’t be reached
>   localhost refused to connect.

I have tried changing different ports but none of them worked for me.

In IE after uncommenting, the below lines in polyfills worked fine in `src/polyfills.ts`

```
/** IE9, IE10, and IE11 require all of the following polyfills. **/
```

**Output of ng --version**

> @angular/cli: 1.0.5
>
> node: 6.9.1
>
> os: win32 x64
>
> @angular/common: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/compiler: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/core: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/forms: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/http: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/platform-browser: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/router: 4.1.3
>
> @angular/cli: 1.0.5
>
> @angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.3

Comment: In Chrome try `settings` - `additional settings` - `network/proxy` - `lan settings` - `auto-detection`

Comment: Are you possibly running chrome using a VM or some sort of container? The message makes sense in the case where "localhost" is not the same machine as what this is running on. Of course you can always `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` if something like that is the case. But then you would still need to point the browser to the actual IP of where the dev server is running

Comment: ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the project has spaces in the path, so I tried to create a new one in a different path without spaces. E.g.: "C:\Users\Me\Documents".

Note: I have to allow NodeJs in the windows firewall.

I hope this information be uselful.